# Solving $\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt[4]{9-x}>\sqrt{3}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, roots

> How to solve this inequality?
> $$\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt[4]{9-x}>\sqrt{3}$$

The solution is $$-3\leq x \leq 9$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Consider $[-3,0]$ and $[0,9]$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

Here there are some hints:

- First, note that for $\sqrt{x+3}$ and $\sqrt[4]{9-x}$ to be defined, $x$ needs to be bounded from below and from above. Which values are those?
- Moreover, it is true for $x>0$ (check the values of $\sqrt{x+3}$ in that case).
- Same for $x<0$ (check the values of $\sqrt[4]{9-x}$, noting that $\sqrt[4]{9}=\sqrt{3}$).
- And finally, the case of $x=0$ is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: I like your hints...